# Two inputs for the same value in Shiny

Tags: html, r, input, slider, shiny

I'm new to shiny and i don't know anything about html, I'm having an issue to find a way to get a slider and a numeric input at the same time for the same input value in my app. Also I would like that when i for instance set the numeric value to 25 the slider automatically sets itself to 25 once the button is pushed.
Thank you for your help.
I tried that for my ui but it doesn't work ...

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "num1",
               label = "Jour limite",
               value = 10, min = 1, max=500),
  sliderInput(inputId = "num",
              label= "Jour limite",
              value= 10 ,min=1 ,max=500
  ),
  actionButton(inputId="clicks",
               label= "Actualiser"),
  plotOutput("courbj")

))
```

Don't know if it's relevant but here is my server code :

```
print(getwd())
CourbeTot <- read.table("data/CourbeTot.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";")



shinyServer(
  function(input,output) {
  valeur <- eventReactive(input$clicks, {
    (input$num)
  })



  output$courbj <- renderPlot({
    plot(CourbeTot$DFSurvieTot.time,CourbeTot$DFSurvieTot.ProptionAuDelaDe,xlim=c(1,2*valeur()))
  })

})
```

Comment: I think you need something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465411/r-shiny-passing-reactive-to-selectinput-choices

Comment: I don't understand why this is the same problem as me but to be fair i didn't exaclty understand what his problem was ( english is not my mother tongue sorry). But if i'm not mistaken his issue is a bit more complex than mine it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set a reactive Input (slider and numeric) using `renderUI` on server site.

here the `UI.R`

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  uiOutput("INPUT"),
  uiOutput("SLIDER"),
  plotOutput("courbj")
))
```

Here the `Server.R`.

```
library(shiny)
print(getwd())
CourbeTot <- 1:10

shinyServer(
  function(input,output) {

    valeur <- reactive({
      S <- input$num
      N <- input$num1
      max(c(10,S,N))
    })

    output$courbj <- renderPlot({
      plot(c(CourbeTot,valeur()))
    })

    # rective slider and numeric input 
    output$SLIDER = renderUI({
      sliderInput(inputId = "num",
                  label= "Jour limite",
                  value= valeur() ,min=1 ,max=500)
          })

    output$INPUT = renderUI({
      numericInput(inputId = "num1",
                   label = "Jour limite",
                   value = valeur(), min = 1, max=500)
    })

  })
```

As you provided no reproducible example I created one. Slider and numeric Input will change according to the other, respectively. This is done 1. per the `max` function which will alwas output the highest value set by one of the two inputs. And. 2 that the inputs are moved to the server side using the `renderUI`. You see that I removed the click button because of problems with the initial `NULL` behavior. Upon this error you can't (or I found no way) select one value and update the other after the click. This seems to be a shiny bug asked already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35792052/initial-state-of-eventreactive). The code is not perfect, but I think it is a good basis to play around and you can adjust it for your purpose.

Comment: This looks like what I intended to do even if I may not have made myself very clear. I'll look into it to see if i can implement this in my app. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked for me, but I would also like to set the initial value of these two inputs. It seems that they always start with the min.value introduced previously. Is there any way to set a different starting point or an initial value for both of them??